# Is there any tool or method which could show unreferred html class?

Tags: javascript, css

I have some html files which define class inside some tags like `<div class="a">` and used inside css files to specify styles and used inside javascript to get the element using `document.getElementsByClassName` etc.

sometimes, I change the name of class to "b" like `<div class="b">`  and forget to update Javascript or css files which will result in errors.

I am wondering if there is any tool which could help check those kind of issues before running inside the browser?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 1):

You should try [VSCode IDE](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the extension named [IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion).